# How to allow arbitrary 'update' functions to be passed to a requestAnimationFrame loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
function animateLetter(letter, type){
    letter.css(type, '50%');
    var j = 50;
    loop(function(){
    letter.css(type, (j =- 5) + '%'); 
    return j < 0;
    });
   }

   function loop(run) {
       if(run.apply()) requestAnimationFrame(loop(run));
   }
```

Why would this not work? I'm new to JS so might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4):

The `loop` function causes an infinite loop as it calls itself in the invocation of `requestAnimationFrame`.

```
function loop(run) {
   if(run.apply()) requestAnimationFrame(function() { loop(run) });
}
```

Wrapping the call to loop in another function means that it will only be called when the `requestAnimationFrame` callback is called.

Comment: You can also replace `run.apply()` by `run()`